# How to draw an image based on data stored on an array in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I need to create something like this

[image]

in Google Colab. I have all the data on an array. First, I tried using matplotlib to create a horizontal bar chart. I made this based on the examples given on their documentation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n = 4
bars1 = (20, 35, 30, 35)
bars2 = (25, 32, 34, 20)
ind = np.arange(n)    # the x locations for the groups

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

p1 = ax.barh(ind, bars1)
p2 = ax.barh(ind, bars2, left=bars1)

ax.set_ylabel('Bars')
ax.set_title('Divisions of each bars')

plt.yticks(ind)

# Label with label_type 'center' instead of the default 'edge'
ax.bar_label(p1, label_type='center')
ax.bar_label(p2, label_type='center')

plt.show()
```

and this is the result of this code

[image]

This looks good, but has a major limitation: I need to have the same number of intervals on every bar, which doesn't always happen on the first picture. Which library could I use to recreate something like this? I tried searching but I don't know exactly how to specify my problem.

Comment: Where does it say you need the same number of intervals?

Comment: I tried making `bars1` smalled and got a shape missmatch error. And if I do something like `bars1 = (20, 35, 30, 0)` I get the 0 written on the chart.

Comment: What if you replace that `0` with `NaN`?

Comment: @MattDMo if I do this `bars1 = (20, 35, 30, float("NaN"))` the 4th bar doesn't get drawn.

Comment: Where did you get the image? Do you know what that style of displaying numbers is called?

Comment: @MattDMo the image was sent to me by a friend. I believe it was made using Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve that with the code you already wrote.

1. The first thing let's consider is that each bar needs to have an
   accumulated value = 100 (it can be any number) let's called MAX.
2. Then for each bar, you calculate the actual value you have, and if
   it's less of our MAX, add the MAX - current value to your bar.

like that we will have all bars at MAX value.

but you will not have the exact same number of sections in each bar if one of those is already at MAX value. to fix that you will need to calculate the MAX value by finding the maximum value in your bars and add x value to it.

code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def get_added_bar(bars):
    max = 0
    new_limit = 0
    added_val = 5
    vertic_sums = []
    added_bar = []
    for x in bars:
        t=0
        for item in x:
            if t > len(vertic_sums)-1:
                vertic_sums.append(item)
            else:   
                vertic_sums[t]  = vertic_sums[t]+item
            if vertic_sums[t] > max:
                max = vertic_sums[t]
            t=t+1
    new_limit = max + added_val
    t=0
    for x in vertic_sums:
        added_bar.append(new_limit-vertic_sums[t])
        t=t+1
    return tuple(added_bar)

def sum_bars(bars) : 
    vertic_sums = []
    for x in bars:
        t=0
        for item in x:
            if t > len(vertic_sums)-1:
                vertic_sums.append(item)
            else:   
                vertic_sums[t]  = vertic_sums[t]+item
            t=t+1
    return tuple(vertic_sums)

n = 4
# 0 for missing value
bars1 = (0, 35, 30, 35)
bars2 = (25, 32, 0, 20)
added_bar = get_added_bar((bars1,bars2)) #

ind = np.arange(n)    # the x locations for the groups

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

print((bars1,bars2,added_bar))

p1 = ax.barh(ind, bars1)
p2 = ax.barh(ind, bars2, left=bars1)
p3 = ax.barh(ind, added_bar, left=sum_bars((bars1,bars2)), color='white')

ax.set_ylabel('Bars')
ax.set_title('Divisions of each bars')

plt.yticks(ind)
print(ind)

# Label with label_type 'center' instead of the default 'edge'
ax.bar_label(p1, label_type='center')
ax.bar_label(p2, label_type='center')
# ax.bar_label(p3, label_type='center')

plt.show()
```

you can check, I created a working example here:
https://replit.com/join/mgpidbnqfb-amirping

you can change any value in your bars with 0 if it's missing and you will still have it working

[image]

Comment: My problem is that I can only have a fixed number of "sections" on each bar, and my example doesn't. See the comment I added to the question.

Comment: Please post some code to demonstrate what you're talking about. It's not very clear at the moment.

Comment: Please post the code *as text, in the answer itself*. Links to external sites can change or rot, and this answer would be useless without it. It's also not appreciated when you link to sites that require membership/logins.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not getting the results shown in the image on Google Colab. There are no errors being throw, but the chart doesn't look anything like this. It also isn't showing correctly on replit.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to getting a section to not appear is to add a value of [`np.nan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.NAN), not `float("nan")`. So, using this data:

```
bars1 = (20, 35, 30, 35)
bars2 = (25, 32, 34, np.nan)
```

results in this graph:

[image: new graph]

Comment: The problem was that I was using NaN on `bars1`. `float("nan")` also works if I use it on `bars2`. I'm wondering now if I can recreate what I need using this.